# iOS local notification only when the screen is locked and without screen activation ?

Tags: ios

Got 2 questions for the xcode experts : 
- I would like to send a (repeating) local notification only to the locked screen but without having the screen turning on, it is possible ? 
- I also would like to check whether the screen is on or off (for this very purpose) : is there any way with the current IOS version (IOS 7) ?

Many thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, frits it will be very hard to get you app running in background without misusing one of the background modes.

You cannot detect if the devices is locked and you will flood the notification center with messages.

If you do manage to get it working then there is good chance that Appel will reject your app for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the screen by checking the applicationState property, which will be set to [UIApplicationStateInactive](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIApplicationStateInactive) when the phone is set to lock/sleep (as opposed to UIApplicationStateBackground).

As for the notification, you can set a push notification delegate (I've not done it from scratch, but I did it using Urban Airship and creating my own custom push handler class) and handle whether to post an alert or not there. I'm not sure, though, whether having the phone sleep will kick notifications to the OS level, which would default to showing a notification on the screen.